# CSS3 column layout with dynamic number of columns

Tags: css, layout, overflow, grid-layout

I have a set of images that I want to display in the following pattern:

```
[1] [4] [7] [10] [13]
[2] [5] [8] [11] ...
[3] [6] [9] [12]
```

I know that I can always manually group 3 images into a `div.column` or something similar, but I want to achieve this layout with as simple HTML as possible. The images are 225x150.

---

Currently, I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='album'>
    <img src='img/01.jpg' />
    <img src='img/01.jpg' />
    ...
</div>
```

And here's my stylesheet:

```
.album {
    background: #faa;
    display: block;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 460px;

}
.album img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

[Chapter 8.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#overflow-inside-multicol-elements) in the specs describes that if I specify a height and the content won't fit in, more columns are created as needed, which is basically just what I want.

As you can see, I specified a background color for the `.album`. This does only cover the first two columns though, since I set the width to `460px`. However, I really need an element that has the exact size/width of the album's content, i.e. an element wrapping the album with that exact size.

None of the possibilities I tried seemed to work tho. (`100%`, `auto`, played with `overflow` as well)

Does anyone have an idea on how I could create such a wrapper element for my albums?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be stuck using Flexbox for this purpose, since using columns within inline elements (inline-block, etc.) causes some browsers to miscalculate the width of the element.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/vuxjF

```
.album {
  background: #faa;
  height: 480px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  .album {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
}

.album img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but my main problem persists. How would I make the `.album` have the minimum width to fit its content or wrap it in an element with that size?

Comment: Alternatively, how would I force certain images to be in a new column?

Comment: The height is forcing the elements to wrap.  Webkit/Blink apparently has a different interpretation of inline-flex than Presto, and it works exactly as expected there :-(.  Not sure who is correct here.

Comment: So you're saying that your .album always has the same width as all columns combined?

Comment: Yes, it shrinks to fit.  There probably isn't a pure CSS solution for this problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Similary thing was asked also at [With column-count, can you dynamically change from 3 to 2 columns if resolution smaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254202/with-column-count-can-you-dynamically-change-from-3-to-2-columns-if-resolution). CSS [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) answered there might be good to check? (columns is a shorthad for column-width + column-count, see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#columns0) & [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/CcGlE)).

Note that browser support varies & -moz/-webkit prefixes are needed currently (http://caniuse.com/#search=column).